# Rails: Testing that an Email Sends with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rspec-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app where I'm trying to test to see if a method properly triggers an email.  I know that it works from testing it from the console.  However, I can't get my test to pass the RSpec test.

What should happen is if there is an Article from yesterday that has not been reviewed yet, it should send an email.

```
# article.rb
scope :yesterday, where(:date=>Date.yesterday)
scope :not_reviewed, where(:reviewed=>nil)

def self.articles_not_updated
  @articles_not_updated = Article.yesterday.not_reviewed
  if @articles_not_updated.present?
    Mailer.articles_not_updated(@articles_not_updated)            
  end
end

# article_spec.rb
context "articles not updated" do

  it "should send an email if there are articles not reviewed" do
    @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article, date: Date.yesterday, reviewed: nil)
    Article.articles_not_updated
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?.should be_false      
  end

end
```

I keep getting the failure message that it returns false.  I have also tried using `Mailer.should_receive(:articles_not_updated)`, but that test also fails.  Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

* Update - Adding Error Message *****

```
expected: false value
got: true
```

Comment: Are you sure `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` is set to `:test`?

Comment: Would you share your specific error message?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I just checked.  Yes, it looks like config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test in test.rb

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I added the error to the description.  Thank you

Comment: One weird thing I noticed with this test is that when it shows the results of all the tests in the spec, instead of just putting "[31mF", it also puts the hash in the results.  I can always see where the failure is because it shows a #<Article:0x6c8a8a0> preceding the "[31mF".

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, you might want to change your description of the failure from "... that it returns false." to "... that it returns true."

Comment: When you tested whether `Mailer` received `:articles_not_update` did you place the expectation *before* the `Article.articles_not_updated` statement?

Comment: No, it was after the Article.articles_not_updated statement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34414/discussion-between-peter-alfvin-and-yellowreign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our chatroom conversation, `should_receive` needs to appear prior to executing the code that is expected to send the message in question. This at least explains why your alternate test was failing.